# Angular.io no imprime mi formulario

Tags: html, angularjs-2.0, bucle-for

Buenos días, estoy creando un componente puro para generar formularios.
El problema que tengo es que me genera las etiqueta  bien pero me muestra el código HTML en vez de imprimirme el input.

Este es mi código:

```
<div *ngFor="let i of cols" class="form-group">
    <input 
        type="{{i.type}} "
        class="form-control" 
        name="{{i.id}}" 
        placeholder="{{i.title}}"
        ... />
</div>
```

Y me imprime esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se cómo hacer que me genere el código.

Comment: Sospecho que tú código está dentro de otro componente. Si pones el código en el que creas el componente en el que está este fragmento, tendríamos más info para intentar ayudarte

Comment: `<div class="app">
      <app-createform 
        [cols]="cols"
        [empresaSelected]="empresaSelected"
        (onChange)="onChange"
       >
     </app-createform>
    </div>`

Comment: Este es el código

Comment: Pero ponlo en tu pregunta, y también la definición del componente, no el html, el js.